# Retrieving PubMed IDs and title: HTTP error

Tags: r, pubmed

I have written a R code to fetch Pubmed IDs and title using the journal name, date, volume, issue and page number.

The file contains rows like

```
AAPS PharmSci 2000 2 1 E2
AAPS PharmSci 2004 6 1 1-9
```

And the output I want is like:

```
AAPS PharmSci 2000 2 1 E2, 11741218 , Molecular modeling of G-protein coupled receptor kinase 2: docking and biochemical evaluation of inhibitors.
```

similarly for all the rows in the file

The code I have written in R for this is

```
    search_topic <- "search term"

    search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic)
    #summary(search_query)

    # see the ids of our returned query
    ID <- QueryId(search_query)

    # get actual data from PubMed
    records<- EUtilsGet(search_query)

    # store it
    pubmed_data <- data.frame(ID,'Title'=ArticleTitle(records))
    write.csv(pubmed_data, file = paste("./",search_topic,".csv",sep=""))
```

Which gives an error like:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open: HTTP status was '502 Server Hangup'
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: works for me (at least doesn't give any warnings or errors, although not all queries have hits).  Did you read the "Note on Usage" in `?EUtilsGet`, i.e. were you careful not to send to many requests too quickly?  You may have gotten your IP address blocked ...

Comment: But then how do I write "pubmed_data" in one file instead of writing it in multiple file? And how do I take care of "too many request too quickly"?

Comment: (1) hard for me to know exactly what's going on at your end (you *might* have been blocked, don't know how long that lasts, or you might be having some other kind of [hopefully transient?] network error). (2) writing to one file is really another question, but you can use `write.table(...,sep=",",append=TRUE)` (`write.csv` ignores the `append` argument!); (3) `?Sys.sleep` ...

Comment: Perhaps related: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/home/bulletins/https-tests.shtml